# how to properly install/ update haskell packages in mac osx

Tags: haskell, haskell-platform

I am totally noob in Haskell, I am trying to follow [a tutorial](http://yannesposito.com/Scratch/en/blog/Yesod-tutorial-for-newbies/) on how use it for the web.

I am using Mac OSX so I downloaded the haskell platform for OSX from http://www.haskell.org/platform/mac.html

Then I did

```
cabal update
```

It told me that a new version of cabal install was available, so why not
    cabal install cabal-install

It compiled version Cabal-1.16.0.3 and installed it in my $HOME/Library/Haskell. 
I prepend $HOME/Library/Haskell/bin to my $PATH and open a new terminal.

Then I do 
    cabal --version

But version is 1.14
I do 
    $HOME/Library/Haskell/bin/cabal --version
And I get that the binary is using library version 1.14
How can I get it to use the newly installed version instead of the one of the platform?

Then I do
    cabal install cabal-dev

And get a message of the new packages to compile but this message also includescabal:

```
The following packages are likely to be broken by the reinstalls:
network-2.3.1.0
haskell-platform-2012.4.0.0
cgi-3001.1.7.4
HTTP-4000.2.5
```

I do not like how this sounds.

I prevously tried to install yesod on a different computer and I remember having the same kind of issues and ultimately yesod was not installing, I do not want to do anything that will break anything this time.

What is the correct way to get Yesod or any haskell package to work on mac osx?

Comment: have you tried serverfault?

Comment: It is more a beginner programmer kind of question than a server related question

Comment: "I do not like how this sounds." You're a wise person. The `cabal-dev` version from github should compile fine. Clone the repo, cd into it, and `cabal install`.

Answer (score 3):

> How can I get it to use the newly installed version instead of the one of the platform?

As cabal should tell you, you just add the directory to your PATH environment variable. For example, if you use bash as your shell, add

```
export PATH=$HOME/Library/Haskell/bin:$PATH
```

to $HOME/.bashrc and restart your shell.

> What is the correct way to get Yesod or any haskell package to work on mac osx?

This question is not OSX-specific, but cabal-specific. The answer is to tell cabal *all* the packages you care about having installed. For example, you might try

```
cabal install cabal-dev haskell-platform # or
cabal install cabal-dev async cgi fgl GLUT haskell-src html HTTP HUnit mtl network OpenGL parallel parsec QuickCheck random regex-base regex-compat regex-posix split stm syb text transformers vector xhtml zlib
```

Or, if you just want to prevent certain packages from being rebuilt, you can use the `installed` constraint as in `cabal install cabal-dev --constraint "haskell-platform installed"`.